# how to call another activity using listview item row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am making an application in which fetching data from xml using url in listview, now i want to call another activity using listview item row, for example :- if user will click first listview row, then need to call item.class, actually i am able to call another activity if i will not use web url in next activity,but if i want to call activity that also fetching data from url using xml parser, then i am getting this error :- Unfortunately app has stopped, why, please someone tell me how can i solve this?

**First.java:**

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) 
{
    if(position==0)
    {
            Intent in = new Intent(First.this, Item.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
}
```

**Item.java:**

```
    public class Item extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://***.net/android/item.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_NODE = "pick"; // parent node
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    }
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
      <activity
        android:name=".First"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Item"></activity>
```

Comment: you should use Thread for fetching data from url.

Comment: can you post your logcat error ?

Comment: Munish, i am able to fetch data in both the activities separately, if i want to call another activity using First activity's listview item row then only i am getting this problem, simply i have made all the modules now i am converting it to a single project only, not facing fetching problem facing problem to call another activity which also consists url data

Comment: Ramindu, if i use debug to test, then getting ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity line:2059, and if i use run to test, then getting unfortunately app has stopped

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the error :  `<activity android:name="Item"></activity>`

it must be

```
 <activity android:name=".Item"></activity>
```

Comment: i disagree because before call url data activity directly from listview row , i have tried this code using to call simple activity like : with some textviews and imageview, and i was able to call and view next activity..help

Comment: if debug then getting this :-ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2059 Source not found

Comment: Please check your "Caused by": in error stack. This line will give you a reason for the error and the line below will show you where the error is happening and will include a line reference so you can easily find the problem.

Comment: yes, really helpful, i have found the reason, now it is working, thanks to all of you those helped me....bye...

Comment: please print error log here when i can find actually issue.