# Displaying ListView Items in another activity thruough onItemLongClick method

Tags: android, android-listview

How to display the details of any of the items clicked in a listview in another activity?
I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889609/how-to-call-another-activity-using-listview-item-row). But unfortunately couldn't understand as to how to go about in displaying the details. Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: put your main code part so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use putExtra of intent and can pass any value or  any serialized class object

yourActivity.java

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) 
 {
   Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this,item.class);
   intent.putExtra("item",parent.getSelectedItem().toString);
   startActivity(intent)
}
```

item.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String itemText = intent.getStringExtra("item");
textView.settext(itemText);
```

hope u got the point..: